# Moisture detection when connecting external hard-drive to tablet

Tags: usb, hardware, tablet

I have a Fire HD 10 Tablet with android in it and i'm trying to use external USB (like storage or mouse) but when i plug the tablet to an USB-Hub connected to a SD Card it reads it for about 10 seconds and then throws the message "Moisture/Water detected, please unplug the USB".
The thing is i tried this with another tablet and it's the same.
However, i tried with my PC and it works fine, so the problem can't come from the USB-Hub or the SD Card.

Any suggestions how i can solve this?
(I know it's more a hardware topic here, but maybe the problem can come from software too?)

Comment: Keep your test set-up as simple as possible. I would start with a direct connection without USB hub (just a mouse or an USB stick). And try different USB cables.

Comment: Sounds like a Comm error. I would try PE ground to 0V on Android